# Maximum achievable mechanical work when heating water

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, work

I am doing a question about finding maximum achievable mechanical work when 1L of liquid water is heated from T₁ to T₂ at atmospheric pressure. The solution is
$$W = \int_{T_1}^{T_2} \frac{T - T_1}{T} mc\,dT.$$ 
I can’t find this formula in my book or on the Internet. I don’t understand the meaning of this equation. It seems like it is the first law $Q - ΔU$ after it is integrated (but if that’s the case, then $ΔU = T_1ΔS$ which seems not to be correct besides its dimension). Can anyone help me? Thanks.

Comment: If you are heating water you are supplying energy. Do you mean using an ideal Carnot engine for extracting mechanical work from that quantity of heat?

Comment: The question doesn’t state how to extract the work, and it doesn’t explain the term ‘maximum achievable mechanical work’ either.

Comment: Search through your book for a section on "exergy" (also sometimes called "availability"). If this section exists, it should cover the idea of the maximum achievable mechanical work.

Comment: Is this supposed to be liquid water or water vapor?

Comment: Thanks for telling me about the term exergy because I have never heard of it before. I have googled it and found that T₁ΔS is the energy lost for irreversiblity(gouy-stodola theorem), which makes perfect sense in the equation now.

Comment: Maybe the question is it incomplete? It should be added that the atmosphere behaves like a source of temperature at temperature T1?
There may be a sign problem : if $T2 > T1$, there is little chance of recovering work and the integral is positive ?